# Can't enable mpm_prefork with Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I'm installing PHP 5.4 with Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.
Php 5.4 is not available on apt-get so I have to install it from source. 
I have installed

```
apache2-prefork-dev
apache2-mpm-prefork
```

And i configured PHP with

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2 --with-mysql --with-curl
```

Then i build and install. I added this lines to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
LoadModule mpm_event_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
LoadModule php5_module  modules/libphp5.so
AddType application/x-http-php  .php
```

When I try to restart Apache I get this error:

```
module mpm_event_module is already loaded, skipping
```

I searched inside the .conf file, but the module was not loaded there before. 
EDIT:

As by @Andrew Schulman answer I could find it in

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_event.load
```

When I run

```
a2enmod mpm_event
```

I get this:

```
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_event:
Considering conflict mpm_prefork for mpm_event:
Considering conflict mpm_itk for mpm_event:
```

How do I solve the conflict?

EDIT2:

I used

```
a2dismod
```

on

```
mpm_event_module
```

and loaded the mpm_prefork_module. Apache restarts ok, but when I try to run

```
a2enmod mpm_prefork_module
```

I get this:

```
ERROR: Module mpm_prefork_module does not exist!
```

What does it mean?

Comment: You need to disable mpm_event, then enable mpm_prefork.

Comment: Look again at the commands I wrote in my answer.  You want `mpm_prefork`, not `mpm_prefork_module`.

Comment: Hint: If you type `a2enmod mpm_pre` and press TAB, the shell will take care of the rest for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find it by grepping through the whole Apache configuration:

```
grep -r mpm_event_module /etc/apache2
```

It's almost certainly in /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_event.load.  In Debian/Ubuntu the standard way of enabling and disabling Apache modules is to run e.g.

```
a2dismod mpm_event
a2enmod mpm_prefork
```

See `man a2enmod`, and similarly `man a2enconf` and `man a2ensite`.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Schulman. Your solution is working. I used `a2dismod mpm_event
a2enmod mpm_prefork`. Thanks.